# How to join unique strings from a column in dataframe based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to join unique strings within one column based on values from another column.

I tried groupby, but either I'm missing something obvious or it's an overkill.

Below is input dataframe. I want to join unique strings from `col2` for each value in `col1`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', '', 1],
    ['a', 's2', 2],
    ['a', 's2', 3],
    ['a', 's3', 3],
    ['b', '', 4],
    ['b', 's1', 5],
    ['c', '', 6]],
  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col0'])
```

I'm looking for output like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['a', '', 1, 's2;s3'],
    ['a', 's2', 2, 's2;s3'],
    ['a', 's2', 3, 's2;s3'],
    ['a', 's3', 3, 's2;s3'],
    ['b', '', 4, 's1'],
    ['b', 's1', 5, 's1'],
    ['c', '', 6, '']],
  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col0', 'col_out'])
```

I tried to play with transform, but none of these provide correct column. I'm not stuck to groupby, transform, any other approach is fine as long as works correctly.

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: ';'.join(x))
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False)['col2'].transform(lambda x: list(set(x)))
df['col5'] = df['col4'].str.join(';')
```

Comment: Should it not be s2;s3 for 1st col?

Comment: `df.mask(df.eq('')).groupby('col1').transform(lambda x: ';'.join(x.dropna().unique()))`

Comment: Sure, you are right, @ParijatBhatt - fixed.

Comment: @user3483203, I got such warning ```FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison result = method(y)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are quite close, add a `strip` here:

```
df2['col_out2'] = df2.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: ';'.join(x.unique())).str.strip(';')
```

It has output:

```
  col1 col2 col0 col_out col_out2
0   a        1   s2;s3   s2;s3
1   a   s2   2   s2;s3   s2;s3
2   a   s2   3   s2;s3   s2;s3
3   a   s3   3   s2;s3   s2;s3
4   b        4   s1      s1
5   b   s1   5   s1      s1
6   c        6
```